# How to configure Detox to be able to use Android emulator running already

Tags: android, react-native, detox

wix/Detox tool tries to launch Android emulator by default, so if there's emulator running already then the error "Running multiple emulators with the same AVD" appears most times (however not always...). Question is, can you configure Detox such way that it would use the emulator running already and not trying to setup new one?

It seems the react-native-firebase team is using Detox this way already, just cannot understand how they manage to do so (see the link below). Could this kind of approach be documented also in the Detox documentation?
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/90b4d7021aff7d5d28140b57eb69283b04712257/.github/workflows/tests_e2e_android.yml#L132-L175

```
root@df3aaa6b6563:/pwd# nohup $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -avd "NEXUS_6_API_30" -noaudio -gpu swiftshader_indirect -camera-back none -no-snapshot -no-window -no-boot-anim -nojni -memory 4048 -timezone 'Europe/Helsinki' -cores 4 &

root@df3aaa6b6563:/pwd# yarn e2e-test-android --tags @freepath
yarn run v1.22.19
$ NODE_ENV=ci DETOX_CONFIGURATION=android.emu.debug DETOX_RECORD_LOGS=failing DETOX_HEADLESS=true DETOX_GPU=swiftshader_indirect DETOX_TAKE_SCREENSHOTS=failing DETOX_RECORD_VIDEOS=failing cucumber-js ./e2e/features -f json:e2e/report/cucumber_report.json --require-module ts-node/register --require 'e2e/features/step_definitions/*.ts' --tags @freepath

*** In Cucumber BeforeAll hook for Detox  ***

nohup sh -c 'yarn e2e-start' > ./metrobundler.log 0</dev/null &
Running detox.init ...
stdout:
stdout:
stdout:
stdout:
stdout:
stdout:
15:16:14.313 detox[15538] ERROR: [SPAWN_FAIL] `/opt/android/emulator/emulator -verbose -no-audio -no-boot-anim -no-window -gpu swiftshader_indirect -port 11062 @NEXUS_6_API_30` failed with code 1
  err: ChildProcessError: `/opt/android/emulator/emulator -verbose -no-audio -no-boot-anim -no-window -gpu swiftshader_indirect -port 11062 @NEXUS_6_API_30` failed with code 1
      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/pwd/node_modules/child-process-promise/lib/index.js:132:23)
      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
      at ChildProcess.emit (domain.js:475:12)
      at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)
15:16:14.315 detox[15538] ERROR: [SPAWN_FAIL] ERROR   | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD
ERROR   | is an experimental feature.
ERROR   | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.
```

UPDATE 27.09.2022: Now that I investigated this further I think I found out the reason why the problem above occurs. It is because of interrupting Detox run e.g. with CTRL+C, then the Detox cleanup will not be run and some resources will remain hanging. In Detox trace logs it is shown 'Device emulator-13196 is already taken, skipping...'. In other words, if Detox will not be forcely interrupted then it is able to use emulator running already, so my mistake. There's question still, how you should recover from the Detox hanging resources situation? Sometimes it helps starting emulator with different random port. I would of course kill needed hanging processes if I just could find them (could not find anything hanging with ps cmd grepping with 'detox'). Probably this is not an issue in most cases in CI, especially if you have different cloud machine for every run.

```
14:48:10.516 detox[73180] DEBUG: [EMU_BIN_VERSION_DETECT] Detected emulator binary version { major: 31, minor: 3, patch: 10, toString: [Function: toString] }
14:48:10.516 detox[73180] DEBUG: [ALLOCATE_DEVICE] Trying to allocate a device based on "NEXUS_6_API_31"
14:48:10.519 detox[73180] DEBUG: [EXEC_CMD, #2] "/Users/jari/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb"  devices
14:48:10.559 detox[73180] DEBUG: [EXEC_SUCCESS, #2] List of devices attached
emulator-13196  device


14:48:10.561 detox[73180] DEBUG: [DEVICE_LOOKUP] Device emulator-13196 is already taken, skipping...
14:48:10.563 detox[73180] DEBUG: [ALLOCATE_DEVICE] Settled on emulator-15874
14:48:10.566 detox[73180] DEBUG: [SPAWN_CMD] /Users/jari/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -verbose -no-audio -no-boot-anim -gpu swiftshader_indirect -port 15874 @NEXUS_6_API_31
14:48:13.053 detox[73180] ERROR: [SPAWN_FAIL] `/Users/jari/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -verbose -no-audio -no-boot-anim -gpu swiftshader_indirect -port 15874 @NEXUS_6_API_31` failed with code 1
  err: ChildProcessError: `/Users/jari/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -verbose -no-audio -no-boot-anim -gpu swiftshader_indirect -port 15874 @NEXUS_6_API_31` failed with code 1
      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/jari/git/omapolkumobile/node_modules/child-process-promise/lib/index.js:132:23)
      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
      at ChildProcess.emit (domain.js:475:12)
      at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)
14:48:13.055 detox[73180] ERROR: [SPAWN_FAIL] INFO    | Android emulator version 31.3.10.0 (build_id 8807927) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found AVD name 'NEXUS_6_API_31'
INFO    | Found AVD target architecture: x86_64
INFO    | argv[0]: '/Users/jari/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator'; program directory: '/Users/jari/Library/Android/sdk/emulator'
VERBOSE |  Found directory: /Users/jari/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64/
emulator: INFO: Found systemPath /Users/jari/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64/
WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
ERROR   | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD
```

Comment: Detox's selection of a running emulator is a feature that works out of the box - there's nothing you should be doing in order for that to work, in particular.

Could you rerun Detox in verbose mode and share the logs? At some point, the `adb devices` command should be logged, which could provide more info as to why the running device isn't selected.

Comment: @d4vidi this problem seems to be my mistake. I think I have reached the error situation by killing Detox run by force (CTRL+C) and  then the Detox cleanup did not happen and causing unwanted behaviour (running emulator seems to be reserved already and Detox skips it). Question still: any idea how should I clean this error situation without booting machine? Any possibility to force Detox cleanup afterwards etc? I would kill any hanging process it I just could find those...

Comment: Detox manages a simplified device locking DB in a temp folder. On a mac, it would be under `~/Library/Detox`. Even though Detox does this anyways whenever you run `detox test`, you can try to erase `*.lock` under that folder.

Comment: Erasing *.lock solved the issue, not getting anymore 'Running multiple emulators with the same AVD' error even if I need to break previous run with CTRL+C.  The reason why I need to do this is because I'm using Cucumber as runner then I'm not using 'detox test' (but 'await detox.init(detoxConfiguration)' instead), thanks @d4vidi

Comment: Interesting, tricky case. We didn't aim for Detox to be used in that specific way. We will try to take that into account in future refactors -- generally opting to eliminate the lock file(s) completely.